# SED to spit out nth and (n+1)th lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

EDITS: For reference, "stuff" is a general variable, as is "KEEP".
KEEP could be "Hi, my name is Dave" on line 2 and "I love pie" on line 7. The numbers I've put here are for illustration only and DO NOT show up in the data.

I had a file that needed to be parsed, keeping every 4th line, starting at the 3rd line. In other words, it looked like this:

```
1 stuff
2 stuff
3 KEEP
4 
5 stuff
6 stuff
7 KEEP
8 stuff etc...
```

Great, sed solved that easily with:

```
sed -n -e 3~4p myfile
```

giving me

```
3 KEEP
7 KEEP
11 KEEP
```

Now I have a different file format and a different take on the pattern:

```
1 stuff
2 KEEP
3 KEEP
4
5 stuff
6 KEEP
7 KEEP etc...
```

and I still want the output of

```
2 KEEP
3 KEEP
6 KEEP
7 KEEP
10 KEEP
11 KEEP
```

Here's the problem - this is a multi-pattern "pattern" for sed. It's "every 4th line, spit out 2 lines, but start at line 2".

Do I need to have some sort of DO/FOR loop in my sed, or do I need a different command like awk or grep? Thus far, I have tried formats like:

```
sed -n -e '3~4p;4~4p' myfile
```

and

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 0 || NR % 4 ==0' myfile
```

and

```
sed -n -e '3~1p;4~4p' myfile
```

and

```
awk 'NR % 1 == 0 || NR % 4 ==0' myfile
```

source: https://superuser.com/questions/396536/how-to-keep-only-every-nth-line-of-a-file

Comment: Could you please mention clear expected output in code tags and let us know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done - it's in the middle right after the "new pattern"

Comment: Could you please check command pasted once?

Comment: In simple words how we will get know which line to be printed? Since you are not searching for a specific string etc. Kindly do mention the same.

Comment: My fault @RavinderSingh13, thanks for being patient with me. We spit out whole lines, nothing to search. Pattern is generally `[(line n, line n+1), repeat every 4 lines, start at line 2]` so result is `line 2, line 3, line 6, line 7, line 10, line 11, line 14, line 15, line 18, line 19, etc....`

Comment: sed is for doing `s/old/new` on individual lines **that is all**. If you need to do anything else then don't even consider using sed, just use awk as the result will be some combination of clearer, simpler, more efficient, more portable, more robust, easier to maintain, easier to enhance, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton you forgot the most important one: easier to read

Comment: IMHO that's implied by "clearer" and "simpler".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your `sed`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..12} | sed -n '2~4p;3~4p'
2
3
6
7
10
11
```

Comment: I guess that people are seeing the line numbers and keying on that, but that's there for illustration and doesn't exist in the data (I thought it would clarify things for RavinderSingh13), but the sed command here is all I needed. `sed -n '2~3p;3~4p` is perfect for the pattern of lines and extensible to the whole file.

Comment: The line numbers are to show you the line numbers you will print with our commands. We don't think it's your real data.

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to print lines 2,3 then every fourth line after those two, you can do:

```
$ seq 20 | awk 'BEGIN{e[2];e[3]} (NR%4) in e'
2
3
6
7
10
11
14
15
18
19
```

Comment: Or equivalently `awk '(NR%4) ~ /[23]/'`

Comment: Or equivalently `awk 'index("23",NR%4)'`. Many, many options with @dawg's approach being the most easily extensible since it will work as-is even if you want to search for multi-digit numbers (e.g. print the 43rd and 127th lines out of every 968 lines).

Answer (score 1):

this is the idiomatic way to write in `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR%4==2 || NR%4==3' file
```

however, this special case can be shortened to

```
$ awk 'NR%4>1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2~4,+1p;d' file
```

Use a range, the first parameter is the starting line and modulus (in this case from line 2 modulus 4). The second parameter is how man lines following the start of the range (in this case plus one). Print these lines and delete all others.

Answer (score 0):

In the generic case, you want to keep lines `p` to `p+q` and `p+n` to `p+q+n` and `p+2n` to `p+q+2n` ... So you can write:

```
awk '(NR - p) % n <= q'
```